# An unexpected coredump during return

Tags: c++, gdb

I get a coredump on line 157:

```
123 template <typename T>
124 int X_Queue<T>::pop(T &item, unsigned int timeout)
125 {
126     int nRet = 0;
127 
128     Thread_Mutex_Guard guard(_mutex);
129 
130     if(_lst_item.empty())
131     {
132         nRet = _cond.timed_wait(timeout);
133         if(nRet == ETIMEDOUT)
134         {
135             //printf("cond timed_wait timeout!\n");
136             return nRet;
137         }
138 
139         if(nRet != 0)
140         {
141             //printf("cond timed_wait failed.\n");
142             return nRet;
143         }
144     }
145 
146     if(!_lst_item.empty())
147     {
148         item = _lst_item.front();
149         _lst_item.pop_front();
150     }
151     else
152     {
153         nRet = -1;
154         //printf("no item is pop.\n");
155     }
156 
157     return nRet;
158 
159 }
```

When I used gdb to see the detail, I found nRet is 110(ETIMEDOUT).

If the first `if` were stepped into and nRet were not zero, the function should return. Otherwise, nRet can only be 0 or -1.

How can this happen?

Comment: If you want your code debugged for you, you should post a complete,minimal program.

Comment: The primary suspects would be lack of synchronization in the rest of the code and bugs in your synchronization classes. Use the standard library.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use `gdb` & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). In C++ at `return` time many things do happen (execution of destructors of local variables!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crash on return from a function is often caused by corruption of the stack.

There is probably an uninitialized pointer, out of range access to a data structure, etc. somewhere in the code.  I don't see enough of the program to know what is happening underneath; you'll have to debug it.

You can use some kind of bounds checking program (like valgrind) or outcomment parts of the code, to hone in on the area of code that causes the problem.  (This is not a perfect method for this type of problem, as  when you change the code, the memory stepover may happen in a different place, showing different (or no) symptoms.

If the code which runs (via function calls, etc) in this function is not large, inspecting the code for likely memory stepovers might be enough to fin the problem.

Alternately, as  Basile Starynkevitch pointed out in a comment, a function return in C++ is more complex than it looks.  The crash may be in a destructor which is called during the return from the function, as local variables go out of scope.

Comment: Or some destructor running at `return` time

Comment: Yes, I was editing that in as you commented.  Saw your comment above and was reminded.  Thanks!  (If you want to make that a potential answer, I'll take it out here and he can mark whichever one solved his problem.)

Comment: No, better put it in your answer. Thanks for citing me there!